# Fudion chart with Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, fusioncharts

please help me to implement Fusioncharts API with Laravel project, when i use the CDN i have the result, but my project will be local so i do need the script js. When i donwload it i can not see my charts.

```
<head>
       <!-- Step 1 - Include the fusioncharts core library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <!-- Step 2 - Include the fusion theme -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/FusionCharts.HC.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/FusionCharts.HC.Widgets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/FusionCharts.HC.world.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/FusionCharts.HC.Maps.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/control.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/FusionCharts.HC.PowerCharts.js"></script>



</head>
{{-- <script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script> --}}`
```

[image: This image is with file donwloaded, i can't see my charts, but with cdn i can.]

Answer (score 0):

Creating charts using Laravel 5 framework and FusionCharts

Step 1: Install all the dependencies and include them in the project.

Step 2: Create the FusionCharts controller.

Step 3. Set up view for the FusionCharts controller.

Step 4. Run the server using the command "php artisan serve", and then route to the view.

Step 5. Now the chart will render

Refer the doc-
[https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/charts-laravel-web-application/#:~:text=To%20render%20FusionCharts%20using%20Laravel,most%20straightforward%20installation%20using%20Composer](https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/charts-laravel-web-application/#:%7E:text=To%20render%20FusionCharts%20using%20Laravel,most%20straightforward%20installation%20using%20Composer)

```
<?php
        $barChart = new FusionCharts("bar2d", "myFirstChart" , 600, 400, "chart-container", "json",
            ' {
                "chart": {
                    "caption": "What kind of apps are you building?",
                    "numberSuffix": "%",
                    "paletteColors": "#876EA1",
                    "useplotgradientcolor": "0",
                    "plotBorderAlpha": "0",
                    "bgColor": "#FFFFFFF",
                    "canvasBgColor": "#FFFFFF",
                    "showValues":"1",
                    "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                    "showBorder": "0",
                    "divLineColor": "#DCDCDC",
                    "alternateHGridColor": "#DCDCDC",
                    "labelDisplay": "auto",
                    "baseFont": "Assistant",
                    "baseFontColor": "#153957",
                    "outCnvBaseFont": "Assistant",
                    "outCnvBaseFontColor": "#8A8A8A",
                    "baseFontSize": "13",
                    "outCnvBaseFontSize": "13",
                    "yAxisMinValue":"40",
                    "labelFontColor": "#8A8A8A",
                    " captionFontColor": "#153957",
                    "captionFontBold": "1",
                    "captionFontSize": "20",
                    "subCaptionFontColor": "#153957",
                    "subCaptionfontSize": "17",
                    "subCaptionFontBold": "0",
                    "captionPadding": "20",
                    "valueFontBold": "0",
                    "showAxisLines": "1",
                    "yAxisLineColor": "#DCDCDC",
                    "xAxisLineColor": "#DCDCDC",
                    "xAxisLineAlpha": "15",
                    "yAxisLineAlpha": "15",
                    "toolTipPadding": "7",
                    "toolTipBorderColor": "#DCDCDC",
                    "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                    "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                    "showShadow": "0",
                    "toolTipBgColor": "#153957",
                    "theme": "fint"
                  },

                "data": [{
                    "label": "Consumer general",
                    "value": "60.7"
                  }, {
                    "label": "Enterprise internal app",
                    "value": "41.7"
                  }, {
                    "label": "Progressive Web Apps",
                    "value": "25.1"
                  }, {
                    "label": "Consumer social network",
                    "value": "24"
                  }, {
                    "label": "Desktop web apps",
                    "value": "18.5"
                  }, {
                    "label": "Desktop apps (electron, etc)",
                    "value": "12.3"
                  }, {
                    "label": "Consumer chat",
                    "value": "12.2"
                  }, {
                    "label": "Other",
                    "value": "4.5"
                }]
            }');
        $barChart->render();
    ?>
```